# How django LoginRequiredMixin use templates. How can we pass context_data to the login form template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views, django-login

How django LoginRequiredMixin takes templates. I cound not find anything how it is taking the templates.

I had added account folder inside templates and then LoginRequiredMixin is taking my template but how it is wokring and how can i pass a context data to the template of login form

Comment: `LoginRequiredMixin` doesn't do anything with templates, could you add an example to your question of what you are referring to?

Comment: @lain Shelvington iam trying to pass context data to login template

Comment: @IainShelvington I had posted an answer can you check is it the right approach for passing context data to login html

Answer (score 0):

LoginRequiredMixin does not render anythings.
This mixin just redirect to LOGIN_URL set in settings by default. You can ovveride the url directly in class with this mixin like this:

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '...'
```

By default, login_url settings go to LoginView from [django.contrib.auth.views](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/views.py) and use the **registration/login.html**. So you can create a login.html in a registration directory in your templates dir for overriding just the default template used if you want

Comment: i just added login_url. which point to a class. How can I add redirect_field_name and redirect_field_value in the hidden input of custom login form.
<input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{redirect_field_value}}">

Comment: login_url have to be a url name, not a class.
If you open the link, you can see the code of actual LoginView in django. You can use URLRedirectMixin in same way i guess

Answer (score 0):

What I had done is to pass context data to LoginRequiredMixin Template is shown below. Whether is it a right approach?.

urls.py

```
path('login_url/', views.CustomLogin.as_view(),name='login'),
```

views.py

```
class SettingsPage(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
      login_url = '/login_url/'

class CustomLogin(TemplateView):
      template_name = 'login.html'

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(CustomLogin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['redirect_field_name'] = 'next'
         context['redirect_field_value'] = self.request.get_full_path().split('=')[1]
    return context
```

login.html

```
<form class="login form-signin"  method="POST" action="/accounts/login/">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{redirect_field_value}}">

   <h4 class="form-signin-heading text-center">Login</h4> 
   <input class="form-control mb-2" type="text" name="login" id="id_login">
   <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="id_password">    
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" >Login</button>
</form>
```

Here it will automatically redirect to the `redirect_field_value` after login